# Is there a way to change status bar color?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, user-interface

Since Android Chrome 39, we can change the URL bar color with a simple `<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff0000">`. Automatically, the status bar also take this color, but with a dark overlay.

We can view it on the web fundamentals example : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/device-access/stickyness/additional-customizations#color-the-browser-elements

Is there a way to prevent the status bar to go darker? And thus have a status bar with the same color of URL bar?

Comment: Maybe worth creating a feature request on the Chromium bug tracker?